# Template Override for Admin Template ISIS

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.3.x, overrides, template-override

I'm trying to override the Administrator template ISIS in Joomla 3.4.  I am simply trying to replace the default Joomla logo's with my company logos so that it's branded for my customers.  I want to override this file:

```
/administrator/templates/isis/images/joomla.png
```

So I made a copy of joomla.png and branded it with my logo instead of Joomla.

Now I tried these folder configurations for override, but none of them work:

```
/administrator/templates/isis/html/images/joomla.png

/administrator/templates/isis/html/administrator/templates/isis/images/joomla.png

/templates/my_front_end_template/html/administrator/templates/isis/images/joomla.png
```

What is the correct way to override the Administrator template image files?  Thank you!

Comment: Although this can be achieved with the backend settings, here are more info about overriding the ISIS template: [Customizing ISIS template](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9973/how-to-customize-the-look-of-the-admin-isis-template-with-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to perform an override for this, it's a simple parameter change.

Go to:

**Joomla backend** >> **Extensions** >> **Template Manager** >> **Isis**

Then go to the **Advanced** tab and you will see 2 parameters to change the logo.

The first one changes the logo that you see in the top right hand corner of the admin template and the second parameter changes the logo you see on the admin login page.