# How to remove/hide "Help" button from the admin toolbar?

Tags: templates, administrator, css, template-override, isis-template

How do I remove the "Help" button from the admin toolbar in Isis template?

I have tried placing the following in the Isis template.css file with no luck,

```
#toolbar-help.btnwrapper button.btn-small {
    display:none;
}
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a [**custom.css file for the ISIS template**](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9973/how-to-customize-the-look-of-the-admin-isis-template-with-css-isis-custom-css/9974#9974), then in this file paste the following:

```
div#toolbar-help.btn-wrapper {
    display:none;
}
```

Clear caches and it should be hidden.

## Update

To sum up the most important stuff of the long comments discussion:

@mrbuckmccoy: Make sure the custom.css is loaded with your browser.
Are you able to find the custom.css and your rules in your browser?
Try adding this in your **custom.css** `body {background:#000;}` to see if you get any change -this should actually turn your background to black. Also remember to clear your caches and make sure you don't have other caching mechanisms that could affect the situation.

@mrbuckmccoy First confirm that we are talking for the latest Joomla version, which is **3.5.1.** **Custom.css won't work for versions before 3.4 or so.** Then if you can confirm that this custom.css actually is being created and saved in your administrator/templates/isis/css folder.

If it exists there, and you have J3.5 then it should be loaded. If you previously added your css in the template's original css file and also didn't see the change, then it's possible that there is other caching somewhere else. It can be from htaccess, from the server/hosting, or 3rd party services e.g. cloudflare.

Comment: To complement, the CSS rule can be reduced still more: _#toolbar-help button { display: none; }_

Comment: Hi. I have created a custom.css file and tried both css without any luck. What could I be doing wrong? @FFrewin

Comment: Thanks but the css did not seem to work. Do you have any other suggestions? I have attached a new screenshot of my edits in the custom.css file @AlexVega

Comment: @FFrewin I have attached a screenshot of what I did. Maybe you can advise of what I may be doing wrong? Thank

Comment: I made a quick test, both are correct. Have you cleared the cache from joomla! and the browser?

Comment: @mrbuckmccoy Is the custom.css loaded?

Comment: @FFrewin Hi, I am new at this. What do you mean by "is the custom.css loaded"? I went to Extensions > Template Manager > Clicked on isis under the Template column > Clicked on "New File" > and titled it custom.css under the css folder

Comment: @AlexVega Hi thanks for testing. But yes, I have cleared the Joomla cache and cleared my browser history/cache. Do my screenshots from above look correct? I am still new at this. Thanks

Comment: @mrbuckmccoy: Are you able to find the custom.css and your rules in your browser? Try adding this in your custom.css body {background:#000;} to see if you get any change -this should actually turn your background to black. Also remember to clear your caches and make sure you don't have other caching mechanisms that could affect the situation.

Comment: @FFrewin I do not see my background changing to black, so I cam assuming that the custom.css is not being loaded? How do I load the css? I have attached a new screenshot on top to show my edits. Thanks. (I have cleared the Joomla cache and broswers cache at all testing and also tried in different browser with incognito mode)

Comment: @mrbuckmccoy First confirm that we are talking for the latest Joomla version, which is 3.5.1. Custom.css won't work for versions before 3.4 or so. Then if you can confirm that this custom.css actually is being created and saved in your administrator/templates/isis/css folder. If it exists there, and you have J3.5 then it should be loaded. If you previously added your css in the template's original css file and also didn't see the change, then it's possible that there is other caching somewhere else. It can be from htaccess, from the server/hosting, or 3rd party services e.g. cloudflare.

Comment: @FFrewin You are right, upgrading to Joomla 3.5.1 worked. Thanks so much! But is there a way to upload this custom.css in Joomla 3.4.8?

Comment: @FFrewin Nevermind, I think I got it. Thank you so much again! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @AlexVega Thanks so much for helping! I got it now.

Comment: @mrbuckmccoy, you can mark this answer as the answer of your question.